# Parámetro Rest en una función

Tags: javascript

Estoy estudiando el Parámetro Rest y me he encontrado este ejemplo:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
function sum(...numbers){
    let total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(numbers));
```

No entiendo por qué me da como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Por qué me da ese resultado?
¿Que tendría que modificar para que me sumase los elementos del array?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al aplicar a los parámetros `rest parameter` lo que JavaScript hace es acomodar los parámetros en un array donde cada valor enviado en los parámetros se convierte en un elemento del array, por lo que en este caso `numbers = [[1,2,3]]`, por lo que al sumarlo a 0 lo convierte en string y lo que hace es concatenar.

En este caso como los datos que se envían ya son un array no es necesario aplicar rest parameter, o bien si se puede usar `numbers.flat()` para reducir la profundidad del arreglo.

Comment: También podría destructurar el array si cambia el parametro a `...[numbers]`, pero no sé si esto era su intención.

Answer (score 1):

La solución mas sencilla es simplemente pasarle como parametros a la función, el resultado de hacer un spread:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
function sum(...numbers){
    let total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(...numbers));
```

Es casi lo mismo, salvo por esta parte, originalmente tenias:

```
console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(numbers));
```

Y paso a ser:

```
console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(...numbers));
```

Que es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo que escribes se podria correr sin el spread (...) ya que es siempre un array, tanto al enviarlo como parametro como al recibirlo como argumento es una sola variable.

Pero si lo que estas analizando es como sumar los argumentos dados sin saber la cantidad de ellos, entonces tendiras en usar el spread en los parametros, aqui un ejemplo que te suma los parametros dados sin saber cuantos son.

Tambien se podria hacer con el objeto arguments.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
function sum(...args){
console.log('args:', args);
    let total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        total += args[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(...numbers));
console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(2,3));
console.log(`Resultado de la función: ` + sum(2,2,2,2,2));
```